# Remove specific numbers of XML elements having same tags and attribute values using Element tree in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree, minidom

I have below XML elements from which I want to remove the only 2 of the Item tag from each Flagelemnts and Fav elements using the element tree in Python.

```
<Flagelements>
   <Item Flags="0" />
   <Item Flags="0" />
   <Item Flags="0" />
   <Item Flags="0" />
</Flagelements>
<Fav>
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
</Fav>
```

It's a huge file of XML and I have tried below Code to do the Same.

```
for child in root:
    count=0
    for ch in child:
        for i in ch:
            i.attrib['GUID']=='4df88cf7d0da00000b30927e000007':
            if i.tag == 'Item':
                print(i.tag, i.attrib)
                count=count+1
                if count< 1:
                    ch.remove(i)
```

But it's removing all of the tags with Item tag.

Also, I have tried below code with .findall method

```
for item in root.findall(".//Fav/Item"):
    count=count+1
    if count<3:
        print(item.tag)
        item.getparent().remove(item)
```

But, it's throwing a below error:

**'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getparent'**

Let me know How I can Do the Same.

Thanks in advance.

Sambhawam

Comment: Please upload a valid XML snippet and explain what is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r><Flagelements>
   <Item Flags="0" dummy="1" />
   <Item Flags="0" dummy="2" />
   <Item Flags="0" dummy="3" />
   <Item Flags="0" dummy="4" />
</Flagelements>
<Fav>
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
</Fav></r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
flag_elements = root.findall('.//Flagelements')
for fe in flag_elements:
    items = fe.findall('./Item')
    for idx,item in enumerate(items):
        if idx < 2:
            fe.remove(item)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<r><Flagelements>
   <Item Flags="0" dummy="3" />
   <Item Flags="0" dummy="4" />
</Flagelements>
<Fav>
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
   <Item ShareWhenSavedAsFav="255" />
</Fav></r>
```